# pyinstaller how to include .py in folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, py2exe

My machine is Win7/10 64bits. I have created a simple project to simulate my existing project structure. I simply wanna create an executable to include all .py(s)

structure:

```
folder
|--test.py
|--main.py
|--lib
   |--a.py
   |--b.py
```

test.py

```
from lib.a import a
...
def main(argv):
    print('test.py main()')
    a('test.py');
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
                ['python','main.py','123','456',
                ], 
                shell = True,
                )
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

main.py

```
from lib.a import a
...
def main(argv):
    from lib.b       import b    
    print('main.py main()')
    print(argv[1], argv[2])
    a('test.py');
    b('test.py');
    while True: 
        time.sleep(0.5) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

a.py

```
...
class a (object):
    def __init__(self,
                fm,
                ):
        print('a()', fm)
        sth = {
            'ab': ['aaa','bbb'],
            '#':  [1,2]
        }
        df = pandas.DataFrame(sth, columns = ['ab', '#'])
        print(df)
```

b.py

```
...
class b (object):
    def __init__(self,
                fm,
                ):
        print('b()', fm)
        sth = numpy.array([1,2,3])
        print(sth)
```

python test.py

```
test.py main()
a() test.py
    ab  #
0  aaa  1
1  bbb  2
main.py main()
123 456
a() main.py
b() main.py
[1 2 3]
```

with the following command,

```
pyinstaller test.py -F -p "\\lib"
```

it hangs and file size > 300MB.
Any idea how to make it work? size issue is less important.

UPDATED based on Arty answer:

I've tried on Win10 py3.7.7 with changes in test.py and the following cmd:

C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --noconfirm --onefile --console --noupx --add-data "./main.py;./" --add-data "./lib/;./lib/" "test.py"

it could compile but the running result of dist\test.exe is:

```
test.py main()
a() test.py
    ab  #
0  aaa  1
1  bbb  2
test.py main()
a() test.py
...
```

It is good that can read .py in lib folder. Yet it cannot start main.py via subprocess. I have no idea why it keeps restarting test.py rather that stopped with throwing an error.

Comment: The reason that `main.py` is not found is because you need to do all steps [of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64618135/941531) including modifications of `test.py`, correct verision of `test.py` [can be found here](https://cutt.ly/OgI8WpP). Specifically line `os.chdir(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))` makes it possible for `main.py` to be seen and available, that is because starting working dir of all `.exe` scripts is different from dir where scripts are located hence you have to change it to correct one by `os.chdir...` command mentioned above.

Comment: Let us continue discussion [inside this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223927/discussion-between-arty-and-cherrimon-shop), I already wrote many new comments there and necessary details and waiting there for you to join chat and reply. BTW, my `.spec` file [is here by this link](https://cutt.ly/qgI8hby).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your task, at least on my Windows 10 64-bit machine, next things are needed:

1. Use `Python 3.7`, higher Python versions are not supported by PyInstaller. If you have other versions of Python on your machine then installer Python 3.7 too. I tested on my `Python 3.7.3 64-bit`. I also tested on my `Python 3.8.2 64-bit` and in fact it works too but `.exe` is `297 MB` unlike `44 MB` for the case of `Py 3.7`, so probably Pyinstaller configs are not well tweaked/optimized yet for Py 3.8 that's why very large binary size.
2. Full command for packaging is `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --noupx --add-data "./main.py;./" --add-data "./lib/;./lib/" "test.py"`, in this command is **important** to use full path to pyinstaller exe from `Python 3.7`, on my machine in this command I replaced `pyinstaller` with `C:\bin\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe`.
3. In the beginning of script `test.py` add next lines:

   ```
   import os, sys
   os.chdir(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
   pybin = sys.executable
   ```

   After that use `pybin` variable everywhere instead of `'python'` string in your `subprocess` calls, i.e. instead of `subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py'...` do `subprocess.Popen([pybin, 'main.py'...`.
   Correct version of `test.py` can [be found here](https://tio.run/##ZVCxbsQgDN35CjZAilDb63W4U4YOHTpUOum6VRUiOeeCRAABaZuvT4Fco0rxYLD9bD8/N8Xemt08q8FZH7ENFQ5Tck6ai8zB2DhvWwjpH9UACNnA2/6iPL1ClDF6WvBEvL28np7PZ1KlIdzJ2PMEMnIA@hfLJuSXCtEpDUKwZMhNjTK4zls5/EA7RtnotKbzdsBaNVziGzeJLtDhQSpDpb9@sQPCyZxXJlISIUTupqXMCCs1ueYJO97Qts3L1qv4yTowtBT/20fhVZE8L/dX5P5hl/zj/olUG/RnhTe50IPWade7H2HbsRD87pMQBXFYEVllHjSAo3d8zzBSHRYiCykEruuktMikhCBLT7k4q1dEQfP8Cw)
4. Done! After change of `test.py` packaging command from `2.` produces working executable  `dist/test.exe`.

Comment: any ref of py3.8 not working with pyinstaller? any sign if they'll support it soon? i shall test it in a day or 2. i suppose i hv to try it in conda env. any chance if u can share your .spec file for study?

Comment: please check the update. i regret it's not working on my side yet. maybe i'm missing some packages for your pybin magic.

Comment: @CherrimonShop There is so called tightly related to pyinstaller GUI program `auto-py-to-exe`, and it has a red message warning regarding incompatibility of pytinstaller with Python 3.8 or higher. It says something like "Pyinstaller is not yet supported for Py 3.8 and/or works badly and/or problems were reported by people.".

Comment: @CherrimonShop What doesn't mean "it's not working on my side"? What errors are reported by which program/script at what stage? You were trying on Py 3.8 or Py 3.7, 32 or 64 bit? `pybin` magick is not using any foreign modules it is just a variable equal to `pybin = sys.executable` and `sys` module is just a standard Py module which contains path to Python binary (.exe) inside `sys.executable`.

Comment: @CherrimonShop BTW, You don't really need Conda environment on your machine, Windows PCs have no problem with having regularly installed several versions of different pythons into different dirs. The only thing to do to prevent collisions of pythons is not to set PATH variable at install time, there is such installer's Check-Box to set or not PATH. PATH should be set only for your main Py installation that you use always. Alternative pythons you just run by full path like `C:\bin\Python37\python.exe script.py` also running pyinstaller through `C:\bin\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe ....`.

Comment: I had updated my question. I did test it with 'python' in subprocess. but it couldn't find main.py file. so I suspect the problem is coming from --add-data "./main.py;./"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223927/discussion-between-arty-and-cherrimon-shop).

Comment: @CherrimonShop Next comments I will post to [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223927/discussion-between-arty-and-cherrimon-shop), please go there and we will discuss everything until your task is totally solved.